# PHP sorting array for dropdown with different properties

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dropdown

I have an array with article codes as id's and different properties.

```
$array = array(
    '1234' => array(
        'color' => 'blue',
        'size' => 's',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ),
    '1235' => array(
        'color' => 'blue',
        'size' => 'm',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ),
    '1236' => array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'size' => 's',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ),
    '1237' => array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'size' => 'm',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ),
    '1238' => array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'size' => 'l',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ), 
    '1239' => array(
        'color' => 'black',
        'size' => 's',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    ), 
    '1239' => array(
        'color' => 'green',
        'size' => 'l',
        'material' => 'cotton'
    )
);
```

Now i want to generate multiple dropdowns for every propery for the product id (1236).
So there should be a dropdown "color" and a dropdown "size". "material" can be ignored since there is no difference.

Now comes my problem:
In the 'color' dropdown should only the articles appear where the color is different but the other properties are the same. I have no clue how i can achieve that.
So the new array to generate my dropdown for article '1236' sould look like this:

```
$result = array(
    'color' => array(
        'blue' => '1234'
        'red' => '1236' // the item itself
        'black' => '1239'
    ),
    'size' => array(
        's' => '1236' // the item itself 
        'm' => '1237'
        'l' => '1238'
    )
);
```

It is possible that i also have more properties like 'width' or 'style' etc.

Comment: I understand. But i am since over 3 hours trying to coding something with more than 4 foreach. But still with absolut no progress. I am not expecting a code, more a hint how something like this could be achieved.

Comment: Seems you are also missing something, why `m` is `1237` and not `1235` for example? Try to write some algorithm, how you can make it manually.

Comment: i want to generate the new array for article 1236. m is 1237 because the other parameter should be exactly the same ('color' = 'red')

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution after trying a few more hours.
This works with any properties given. What really helped me was the array_diff() function.

```
function getDropdownsByArticle($id,$array){
    foreach($array[$id] as $thisproperty => $thisvalue){
        foreach($array as $articleid => $article){
            $arraydiff = array_diff($article,$array[1236]);
            if((count($arraydiff) == 1 AND array_key_exists($thisproperty,$arraydiff)) OR count($arraydiff) == 0){
                $dropdown[$thisproperty][$article[$thisproperty]] = $articleid;
            }
        }           
    }
    return $dropdown;
}
getDropdownsByArticle('1236',$array);
```